# How to parse a simple text file in java

Tags: java, parsing, text-files

I would need to parse a text file with below format and extract only the required values from the text file. the content of the text file is

```
4564444   FALSE  /  TRUE    0   name k0LiuME5Q3
4342222   TRUE  /   TRUE    0   id  ab4454jj
```

i need to get the values after name and id. what is the best way. I used Scanner Class in java but could not get the values. tried with below code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        String last = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
        System.out.println(last);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you already tried something. You should edit your question to add a [mcve]

Comment: Share some code

Comment: @Lexi thanks for your comments. added  sample code i tried to split the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Read_Text_File {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getValues());
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getValues() {
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream("src/resources/java_txt_file.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String strLine;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String lastWord = strLine.substring(strLine.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
                lines.add(lastWord);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }

}
```

> Output:
>
> [k0LiuME5Q3, ab4454jj]

Comment: thanks for the code. each line is stored into an array item in your code

Answer (score 1):

You need to split by space, not semicolon:

```
String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Comment: when tried to split the entire content is stored into one array item

Comment: Do you have tabs in the files as separators? Then it is scanner.nextLine().split("\t")

Answer (score 1):

read the data line by line, on each line use String.split("\s*") to get the parts without the whitespace into an array with 7 elements. the last one of these elements is what you are looking for.